# Проблема с автокомплитом в PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Можно ли в PhpStorm вызывать автокомплит меню без нажатия Alt+Space, а чтобы просто во время ввода текста оно само появлялось?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что с подобными вопросами следует обращаться в соответствующую техподдержку.

Answer (score 3):

В нижнем правом углу нажми на значок головы человека и там отключи режим энергосбережения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]